# If $u_m \rightharpoonup u$ in $X$ and $f(u_m) \rightharpoonup g$ in $X$, is $g = f(v)$ for some $v$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X=L^2(0,T;V)$ and let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous and invertible function satisfying $(f(x)-f(y))(x,y) \geq 0.$

Suppose also that $f(u) \in X$ for $u \in X$. ($X$ is for example $L^2(\Omega)$), and that $f^{-1}(v) \in X$ for $v \in X$.

Let $u_m \rightharpoonup u$ in $X$ and $f(u_m) \rightharpoonup g$ in $X$.

Can I write the weak limit $g$ as $f(v)$ for some $v \in X$? i.e. is it true that $f(u_m) \rightharpoonup f(v)$ for some $v \in X$?

Why can't I just take $v := f^{-1}(g)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you get $f(u_m) \rightharpoonup f(v)$ only if $f$ is linear.

For a simple counterexample let $f(-1) = -1$ and $f(1) = 1$. Now, let $u_n$ take only the values $-1$ and $1$ and let $u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ (on $(0,1)$ take $u_n(x) = \mathrm{sign}(\sin(n\,x))$).

Then, $f(u_n) = u_n \rightharpoonup 0$, but $f(0) \ne 0$ in general. The same approach works for any, non-affine $f$.

However, since your $f$ is monotonely increasing, there is a good chance that $f$ is surjective. Hence, there might be a $v$ with $f(v) = g$.